# javascript: Hacer un codigo que permita lo siguiente

Tags: javascript

> Desarrolla una función en la que se pida al usuario que ingrese una frase y la web responda con la cantidad de caracteres que se han escrito y las veces que se repite cada uno de los que forman la frase.

Esto es lo que tengo de momento, pero me falta la parte:

- Las veces que se repite cada uno de los caracteres que forma la frase

```js
var frase = prompt("escribe una frase");
var letra = prompt("elige una letra de dicha frase");
var encontrar = frase.indexOf(letra);
var fraseArray = frase.split('');
var caracteresRepetidos = fraseArray.filter(letraFrase => letraFrase === letra);
var vecesRepetido = caracteresRepetidos.length;
alert("tu frase es: " + frase + " y tiene: " + frase.length + "caracteres" + "\n" + "tu letra " + letra + " se repite " + vecesRepetido + " veces " + ", tu letra esta en la posición " + encontrar);
```

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Podrías utilizar una función `reduce()` sobre tu `string` tras haberla convertido a lista con el `split()`

```
fraseArray.reduce((x,y) => { x[y]=x[y] ? x[y]+1 : 1; return x }, {});
```

```js
var frase = prompt("escribe una frase");
var letra = prompt("elige una letra de dicha frase");
var encontrar = frase.indexOf(letra);
var fraseArray = frase.split('');
var caracteres = fraseArray.reduce((x,y) => { x[y]=x[y] ? x[y]+1 : 1; return x }, {});
var caracteresRepetidos = fraseArray.filter(letraFrase => letraFrase === letra);
var vecesRepetido = caracteresRepetidos.length;
alert("tu frase es: " + frase + " y tiene: " + frase.length + "caracteres" + "\n" + "tu letra " + letra + " se repite " + vecesRepetido + " veces " + ", tu letra esta en la posición " + encontrar);
console.log(caracteres);
```

Comment: pero eso me funciona solo aqui, luego cuando lo ejecuto en mi navegador, me sale en la consola, pero si quisiera que saliera como alert modificando la parte de "console.log(caracteres);"(la última línea), lo cambio por "alert(caracteres)", me sale [object Object]

Comment: Deberías convertir el objeto a string para poder pintarlo en un alert, por ejemplo con JSON.stringify()

Comment: De cualquier manera, cuando dices "eso me funciona solo aqui" estás equivocado. Simplemente tienes que abrir la consola del intérprete donde lo estés ejecutando

Comment: Si, perdón, se me olvidó esa parte, pero lo prefiero en un alert

Comment: Pues itera las propiedades y lo conviertes en string como quieras, o bien usas stringify de JSON

Comment: muchas gracias, ha sido de gran ayuda

Answer (score 2):

Como es un ejercicio, prefiero no darte el código sino la idea general de la solución: En lugar de pensar en cómo iterar repetidas veces por el array de letras, puedes obtener en una sola pasada esa información, usando el método [`reduce` (MDN)](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce), acumulando el número de apariciones de cada letra.

Te pongo un ejemplo:

```
let frase ="Hola Paco";

function cuentaLetras (acumulador, letra) {
   //aquí está la magia
};

let resultado = frase.split('').reduce(cuentaLetras, {});
```

Y `resultado` tendría que valer:

```
{
  "H": 1,
  "o": 2,
  "l": 1,
  "a": 2,
  "P": 1,
  "c": 1,
}
```